# Passar valor de variável através de um botão

Tags: php, html

Existe uma maneira de passar o valor de uma variável recuperada de uma busca no banco de dados para um botão, que redirecionará o usuário para outra página, onde uma nova busca no banco será feita usando o valor da variável?

O código a baixo é usado para a primeira consulta no banco de dados e para mostrar em forma de tabela alguns dados. Dentro dele que está o botão que irá redirecionar para outra página, onde quero usar o valor da variável email para fazer outra busca no banco de dados.

```
<?php
              require_once('conecta.php');
              $pasta = "imagens/";
              $objDb = new db();
              $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();
              $consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM voluntarios WHERE grupo = '' order by nome");
              while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
                $link = $pasta . $resultado["foto"];

                echo '<img src='.$link.' width="100px" height="100px"></br>
                <center><table border=1>
                  <thead>
                    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">   '.$resultado["nome"].'   </td></tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp E-mail &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["email"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Data de nascimento &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["data"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp CPF &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["cpf"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Contato &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["tel"].' / '.$resultado["cel"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Endereço &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp CEP: '.$resultado["cep"].' / Número: '.$resultado["numero"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Instituição &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["instituicao"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Nível  &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["nivel"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Curso &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["curso"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Área &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["area"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Turno disponível &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["turno"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Horário &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["horario"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Habilidades extras &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["habilidades"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Ministrará palestras &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["palestras"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp Cidade &nbsp</td>
                      <td align="center">&nbsp '.$resultado["cidade2"].' &nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table></center>
                <center><a href="vol.php" class="btn btn-custom btn-roxo ">Acessar</a></center></br></br>
                ';
            } 
            ?>
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar $_SESSION ? Tente nos mostrar o seu problema, colocando seu código aqui, assim a comunidade pode dar uma resposta que possa solucionar especificamente seu problema.

Comment: @RickPariz Não tentei com `$_SESSION`, porém como pode acontecer de ter mais de um resultado, será que não teria problema em usar isso? Adicionei o código à pergunta!

Comment: Uma das alternativas é passar o email pela url, ficaria algo como vol.php?email=$resultado['email].

Comment: @RickPariz eu tentei fazer dessa forma, ele passa o valor da variável email, porém não consegui recuperar esse valor na outra página, eu usei igual o amigo abaixo falou `$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta passa a variável via URL.

```
<a href="vol.php?email=' . $resultado["email"] . '" class="btn btn-custom btn-roxo ">Acessar</a>
```

Para obter a variável no script que irá processar a chamada, basta usar:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

ou caso queira um pouco mais de segurança

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: Fazendo dessa forma da certo, ele passa o email, porém eu coloquei um echo para mostrar a variável `$email` mas não aparece nada. Eu usei o `$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

Comment: Deu certo, eu tinha esquecido de colocar `email=`. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: Que bom que deu tudo certo =]